# How to send all rows of table to Jade using node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How do I send all rows of the original console value to Jade using node.js? This code is sending only 1 row of the WCF service to Jade.

```
var response = result['s:Envelope']['s:Body']  [0].OrderReportResponse[0].exeReport[0];
        console.dir(JSON.stringify(response));
        var marketOrder = response['a:MarketOrder'];
        for (var i = 0; i < marketOrder.length; i++) {
            var date = marketOrder[i]['a:SendingTime'];
            var time = marketOrder[i]['a:TransactTime'];
            var buyorSell = marketOrder[i]['a:Side'];
            var orderQty = marketOrder[i]['a:OrderQty'];
            var exchange = marketOrder[i]['a:Exchange'];
            var contractName = marketOrder[i]['a:ContractName'];
            var price = marketOrder[i]['a:Price'];
            var filled = marketOrder[i]['a:mFile'];
            var account = marketOrder[i]['a:Account'];
            var wrkQty = marketOrder[i]['a:WrkQty'];
            var execute = marketOrder[i]['a:ExeQty'];
            var undQty = marketOrder[i]['a:UndQty'];
            var type = marketOrder[i]['a:OrdType'];
            var modifier = marketOrder[i]['a:Modifier'];
            var trigPrice = marketOrder[i]['a:TrigPrice'];
            var status = marketOrder[i]['a:Status'];
            var avgPrice = marketOrder[i]['a:AvgPrice'];
            var tif = marketOrder[i]['a:TimeInForce'];
            var route = marketOrder[i]['a:Route'];
            var originator = marketOrder[i]['a:Originator'];
            var currentUser = marketOrder[i]['a:CurrentUser'];
            var algoName = marketOrder[i]['a:AlgoName'];
            var parentId = marketOrder[i]['a:ParentId'];
            var tTOrderId = marketOrder[i]['a:TTOrderId'];
            var ExchOrderId = marketOrder[i]['a:exchOrderId'];
            //console.dir(JSON.stringify(date, time, buyorSell, orderQty, exchange, contractName, price, filled, account, wrkQty, execute, undQty, type, modifier, trigPrice, status, avgPrice, tif, route, originator, currentUser, algoName, parentId, tTOrderId, ExchOrderId));
            res.render('aaa', {title: date, title1: time, title2: buyorSell, title3: orderQty, title4: exchange, title5: contractName, title6: price, title7: filled, title8: account, title9: wrkQty, title10: execute, title11: undQty, title12: type, title13: modifier, title14: trigPrice, title15: status, title16: avgPrice, title17: tif, title18: route, title19: originator, title20: currentUser, title21: algoName, title22: parentId, title23: tTOrderId, title24: ExchOrderId});
            return res.send();
```

Comment: This code is sending only 1 row of WCF service in UI... how to fetch all data in UI

Comment: tr
                td=title
                td=title1
                td=title2
                td=title3
                td=title4
                td=title5
                td=title6
                td=title7
                td=title8
                td=title9

Comment: Like this i am fetching data in UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table(cell)
    mixin tableRow(data)
      -
        var cols = ['SendingTime','TransactTime','Side','OrderQty','Exchange','ContractName','Price','mFile','Account','WrkQty','ExeQty','UndQty','OrdType','Modifier','TrigPrice','Status','AvgPrice','TimeInForce','Route','Originator','CurrentUser','AlgoName','ParentId','TTOrderId','exchOrderId']

```
  tr
        each col in cols
              if data==='head'
                    th=col
              else 
                    td= data['a:'+col]
```

table
      thead
            +tableRow('head')
      tbody#tt
            each row in orders
                 - console.log(row)
                  +tableRow(row)

Answer (score 0):

You have two major errors. First, in Express, you can only render and send a response once per view. Second, your `return` call causes the loop to immediately exit after the first attempt, so it only returns the first row. If not for the `return` statement. nesting these calls in a loop will cause the last row to render.

Avoid nesting a render call or a response send inside a loop — or even have a loop inside your Express view at all. There's no need to send 25 local variables to your Jade template; just send the `marketOrder` response object to the Jade template, and iterate on the object inside the template to append all rows to your results.

Your Express route code should be something like this:

```
var response = result['s:Envelope']['s:Body'][0].OrderReportResponse[0].exeReport[0];
console.dir(JSON.stringify(response));
var marketOrder = response['a:MarketOrder'];
res.render('aaa', {orders: marketOrder});
return res.send();
```

Inside your Jade template, I'd recommend using a mixin like this to iterate through rows and log the data to the console. Instead of hardcoding a tr value for each column, I included all the names as an array inside the mixin to iterate through. To keep things more DRY, I added a conditional that allows the mixin to be used for the `thead` row as well.

```
mixin tableRow(data)
      -
        var cols = ['SendingTime','TransactTime','Side','OrderQty',
        'Exchange','ContractName','Price','mFile','Account',
        'WrkQty','ExeQty','UndQty','OrdType','Modifier','TrigPrice',
        'Status','AvgPrice','TimeInForce','Route','Originator',
        'CurrentUser','AlgoName','ParentId','TTOrderId','exchOrderId']

      tr
            each col in cols
                  if data == 'head'
                        th=col
                  else 
                        td= data['a:' + col]
```

Then, within the HTML of your Jade file, iterate through the `marketOrder` array to append rows to your table and log that row's respective data server-side as below:

```
table
      thead
            +tableRow('head')
      tbody
            each row in marketOrder
                 - console.log(JSON.stringify(row))
                  +tableRow(row)
```

Comment: I tried your code but still there is error like (Can't remove headers after they are sent.) and no out is coming in My UI.

Comment: And if I am removing (return res.send();) line then there is no error but then too No out in my UI.

Comment: table
      thead
            +tableRow('head')
      tbody
            each row in marketOrder    // in place of marketOrder, shud keep orders
                 - console.log(JSON.stringify(row))
                  +tableRow(row)